# Javascript innerHTML / jQuery .html() IE display bug - adding table to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using an AJAX call to a script which generates an HTML table.

After getting the table's HTML from the script's output, I am replacing a target container `div`'s HTML with the new HTML.

e.g. `$('#table_container').html(data);`
or... `document.getElementById('table_container').innerHTML(data);`

In Firefox, the table is displayed within the div just as I want it to.

In Internet Explorer, the table is displayed, and then underneath the table, there is some extra text, usually 10-20 characters taken from a (seemingly) random location in the table.

I have validated the HTML from the ajax call through the W3C validator.
I am using a doctype at the type of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Why might IE be displaying this extra text?

Comment: What does the `data` string contain?

Comment: Is there any chance that you might link to the actual project?

Comment: Did you check the html being returned? Can you post the contents displayed by IE

Answer (score 2):

I personally have always had better luck with:

```
$("#table_container").empty();
$("#table_container").append(data);
```

Comment: can chain those `$("#table_container").empty().append(date);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the source of the underlying problem is, and I don't know if this will help, but you might try using remove() and appendTo() and see if IE treats it properly. In my experience this usually works better.

```
$(data).appendTo($('#table_container'));
```

Also, if it's possible to link to the actual site, I might be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like there is some text in your string which is breaking the tables html.

Try using

```
$string = htmlentities($string);
```

on the string that is in the table cells ......

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

As it turns out, the problem was because of blank cells in the table.

This will cause the errors:

```
<td></td>
```

This is acceptable:

```
<td> </td>
```

The strange thing (to me) was that if I dumped the HTML to a flat .html file and viewed it, there would be no problem.  But when I used JS to add this same HTML markup to a div, then the problem occurs.

C'est la IE! :-)